# Deploying the root pom.xml to artifactory via jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, artifactory

I'm uploading from jenkins to artifactory and my whole maven project is built with:

```
mvn clean install
```

The project has

[image]

Result of the Deploy to Artifactory:

[image]
[image]

How do I get the root pom.xml to the artifactory? I reference this from other project and it does not build because of it. All the other modules are deployed and their POMs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the reason that it did not work was that I had included an include pattern in the deploy maven artifacts, I removed the ".xml, *.jar" and it deployed correctly.

[image]